# Adding data from one column to existing column in excel using Macros

Tags: vba, excel

I am new to excel and using macros, how can i achieve below inquiry

How to add data to another column by pressing a button in excel?

When user press "SAVE", data from column **B2** will be added to column of column **F**.

I tried to do below code but i doesn't work

```
Sub ButtonSave_Click()
Range("B2").Value = Range("F" & Row).Insert
End Sub
```

[image]

How to deal with this?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the following and replace Activesheet with the actual sheet name e.g. `Worksheets("Sheet1")`

Code:

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub ButtonSave_Click()
With ActiveSheet '<== replace with actual sheet reference
    .Range("F" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row + 1) = .Range("B2")
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi QHarr, thank you for your answer, it works but it replaces the cells, i need is it adds up per row

Comment: Thanks a lot QHarr!

Answer (score 0):

```
Row=Range("F1").End(xlDown).Offset(1,0).Row
Range("F" & Row).Value=Range("B2").Value
```